# implement the onclick on the search Result using searchview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-sqlite, android-search

I want to open the detail activity as i have done in my recyclerview, after the search result shown in recyclerview. As the search Result Updated in the Recyclerview the the onclick to open the Detail activity is not working.

How can implement the onclick in the recyclerview which is updated after the search Result

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, EnquiryAdapter.OnItemClickListener {

    DbHelper mDbHelper;
    public static final String FORM_ID = "form_id";
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private EnquiryAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        mDbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
 //RecyclerView Setup
        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mAdapter = new EnquiryAdapter(MainActivity.this,mDbHelper.getFormData());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(MainActivity.this);
   }

  @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
            SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(SEARCH_SERVICE);
            searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
            searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new  

searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                    searchForm(s);
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                    return false;
                }
            });

            return true;
        }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,DetailedActivity.class);
        int id = EnquiryAdapter.id;
        intent.putExtra(FORM_ID,id);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


    private void searchForm(String keyword){

        SQLiteDatabase db= mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("SELECT * from ").append(FormEntry.COLUMN_TABLE_NAME).append(" where ").append(FormEntry.COLUMN_NAME_NAME).append(" = ?");

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sb.toString(),new String[]{keyword});

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new EnquiryAdapter(MainActivity.this,cursor));

    }
}
```

EnquiryAdapter.java

Adapter Class

```
public class EnquiryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EnquiryAdapter.EnquiryViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private Cursor cursor;
    private OnItemClickListener mListner;
    public static int id;

    public EnquiryAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        this.context = context;
        this.cursor = cursor;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public EnquiryViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.enquiry_list,viewGroup,false);
        return new EnquiryViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull EnquiryViewHolder enquiryViewHolder, int i) {
        if(!cursor.moveToPosition(i)){
            return;
        }

        String nameText = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(FormContract.FormEntry.COLUMN_NAME_NAME));
        String emailText = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(FormContract.FormEntry.COLUMN_NAME_EMAIL));
        int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(FormContract.FormEntry._ID));
        String timestamp = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(FormContract.FormEntry.TIMESTAMP));
        Log.d("TIMESTAMP", timestamp);

        enquiryViewHolder.mNameText.setText(nameText);
        enquiryViewHolder.mEmailText.setText(emailText);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return cursor.getCount();
    }

    public class EnquiryViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView mNameText, mEmailText, mDateText;

        public EnquiryViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mNameText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            mEmailText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.email);
            mDateText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_text);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(mListner != null){
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){

                            cursor.moveToPosition(position);
                            id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(FormContract.FormEntry._ID));
                            Log.d("ID", String.valueOf(id));
                            mListner.onItemClick(position);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }
    public interface OnItemClickListener{
        void onItemClick(int position);

    }
    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
        mListner = listener;

    }

    public void swapCursor(Cursor newCursor){
        if(cursor != null){
            cursor.close();
        }
        cursor = newCursor;

        if(newCursor != null){
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I never implemented Filterable class

Comment: Are you able to retrieve item id in `id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(FormContract.FormEntry._ID));` ?

Comment: yes I am getting the id from that @ronginat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the `OnitemClickListener` inteface to

```
public interface OnItemClickListener{
    void onItemClick(int id);
}
```

Then, in EnquiryViewHolder `itemView.onClick` just send the id instead of the position, you aren't using it anyway.

Comment: It's good, but after search when the recyclerview is updated, the onclick is not working on that item..

Comment: Try not to instantiate a new  `EnquiryAdapter` in every `onQueryTextSubmit`. Instead, use your method `swapCursor`

Comment: Replace `mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new EnquiryAdapter(MainActivity.this,cursor));`
with
`mAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);`

Comment: The Onclick started working but, the list restored when the searchview back button clicked stopped working. The whole list is not showing now.

Comment: What do you mean by "the list restored when searchview back button stopped working"...?

Comment: What do you want to do when searchview back button clicked?

Comment: the recyclerview list, that is populated from my SQLite. after search it shows only the search items, when I press back button after seach it shows me the new list of items which I get from the search Result

Comment: when the back button is press, I want to display the whole list of items again... how can I implement the back button of searchview??

Comment: hey, don't get bothered I have make changes in the code in onQueryTextChange and its works

Comment: in `onCreateOptionsMenu` add `menu.findItem(R.id.search).setOnActionExpandListener(new MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener() { ... }` In the `onMenuItemActionCollapse` implementation swapCursor back to the whole list cursor

Answer (score -1):

[image: searchview with clicklistener recyclerview]

Create a interface in your adapter class.

```
public interface SelectedUser{

    void selectedUser(UserModel userModel);

}
```

implement the interface in you activity and override the selectedUser(UserModel userModel).

and pass the data to your other activity

```
@Override
public void selectedUser(UserModel userModel) {

    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SelectedUserActivity.class).putExtra("data",userModel));

}
```

Find the whole tutorial here.
[RecyclerView with searchview and onclicklistener](https://youtu.be/ujKDN_ZtGHQ?sub_confirmation=1)

Comment: I paid for your source code and got nothing